# ¿Como puedo mostrar los valores null como una columna vacia?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

tengo un `template` `person_report` y necesito que los valores de este concatenamiento no se muestren como `null` cuando se genera un pdf.

```
                <td th:text="|${person.address} ${person.address_number}  ${person.floor}  ${person.department}|">Static content</td>
```

trate con:

```
{person.address?} ${person.address_number?} ...
```

y con:

```
                <td th:text="|${person.address !=null} ? ${person.address_number !=null} ? ${person.floor !=null} ? ${person.department !=null} : '-'|"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una validación donde preguntes que si el campo es null, le asignas un espacio o comillas vacias.

Sería algo como esto:

```
if (empty($person.address)) {
  person.address = " ";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

puedes hacerlo asi

```
if($person.address_number == null){
   //asignación de los valores 
}
```

Comment: tendria que cambiar th:text por th:if?